# Java Spring Application - regarding assigning variable value in application-env.properties file using a Shell Script in the same server

Tags: java, spring-boot, unix, command, properties-file

We have an application in a server for which it's Database connectivity credentials present in application-env.properties file are assigned using a shell script situated in the same server.

```
datasource.username=username
pwp.script=${pwp.location}/bin/pwp -a ${pwp.config.location}/access.cf -f 
           ${pwp.config.location}/password.cf ${pwp.config.location}/GetPw.sh
datasource.password=${pwp.script} oraasdb username
```

Currently datasource.password is getting assigned as null. So we have hardcoded it as a temporary workaround which works. But I am unable to debug from a developer point that what is wrong with the above lines? Is the root cause that the GetPw.sh is not returning any value? How do I get to the root of this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the content of your shell script? Is it setting the env variables before the application is started? if yes, what is the output of `printenv`?